# What changes are there in the "iPhone Developer Program License Agreement"

Tags: iphone, licensing

Recently, the iPhone Developer Program License Agreement has been changed.

Sadly, there is no previous version officialy available for us to compare (as far is i know).
Googling the search term does not reveal very useful results to me (and only very old versions of the license agreement.

If anyone of you has a good understanding of the license agreement and its recent changes, i would be glad to learn from you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did an compare of the two pdf files (you'll have to read the current one to understand what these mean):

changes:

0 - throughout: remove references to specific products and replace with "iPhone OS"

1 - throughout: references to include the federal government added to "your company, organization..." type phrases.

2 - clauses 3.1.17 and 3.1.18 are new to "Content and Materials" section

3 - clause 3.3.24 is new

4 - clause 15.11 - changes for disputes between apple & education institutions

5 - Exhibit A, clause 9 was added.

hope that helps.
(caveat: I'm no lawyer, so who knows what changed from a legal standpoint).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just read the new one. It only takes a few minutes.

-t

Comment: Presumably, because it's useful to know what's changed as well as what the license agreement is now.  I've missed changes in such documents by just reading old and then later reading new, and I've remembered the wrong document.

Comment: Took me less than 15 minutes.

Comment: Considering the text contains 18633 words, this would result in you reading AND understanding about 20 words per second of complex, legal text, which is pretty amazing. What is your secret?